# Make Stylus merge imported CSS into the stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, stylus

I have a Stylus file, looking like

```
@import init
@import typography
@import colors
@import 'components/*'

@import '3rdparty-stylesheet.css'
```

The last line is a CSS file I get from a 3rd party plugin which I want not just to stay as it is when compiled into CSS, but all the content of this file to be injected. I use Gulp.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found how to switch this option on:

```
    gulp.src('./app/styl/style.styl')
    .pipe(stylus({
        'include css': true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
```

And it works like a charm now, puts all imported CSS contents into a single compiled file.

Comment: When I set `compress: true` inside `stylus()`, only the stylus generated CSS is minified. Is there a way to minfy the imported CSS too?

Answer (score 5):

For command line I use this.

> stylus --include-css index.styl

Which I find handy for testing... before incorporating into the build process.

Comment: awesome man!) I just wanted to rewrite all styl to scss)) thanks)